# Demonstrating Piecewise Linearity in a Parametrized Optimization Solution

Tags: convex-optimization, piecewise-continuity, constraint-programming

Let $\mathbf{B}$ be a definite positive square matrix of size $n \times n$, and $\mathbf{b}$ an $n$-sized vector. It can be shown that the solution of $\arg\min_x \left(\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{B} \mathbf{x} - 2\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x}\right)$ is $\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{b}$. Consequently, we can assert that $\mathbf{b} \mapsto \arg\min_x \left(\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{B} \mathbf{x} - 2\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x}\right)$ constitutes a linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

However, when we introduce a positivity constraint, i.e., when we seek the solution in the set of non-negative vectors, I suspect the application $\mathbf{b} \mapsto \arg\min_{\mathbf{x} \geq 0} \left(\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{B} \mathbf{x} - 2\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x}\right)$ to be a piecewise linear function, as my numerical experiments show. What approaches or methods can be pursued to demonstrate this type of result?

EDIT:

1D case, $B$ is a strictly positive number. Then $b \mapsto \arg\min_{\mathbf{x} \geq 0} \left(B x^2-2bx\right)$ is simply $\max(0, b/B)$

Comment: Can you maybe try with Lagrange multipliers and KKT conditions?

Comment: Also, it might help considering the scalar version of the function and plot it

Comment: Check out Section 6.6 in [Lectures on parametric optimization: an introduction by G. Still](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/6587.pdf)

Comment: Very nice reference, I'm reading it, thanks !

Comment: @madnessweasley, could you please post your reference as an answer? This will allow me to grant you the bounty.

Comment: Done. Unfortunately, I currently don't have the time to make my answer self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 6.6 in the reference below has the result you are looking for. In particular, check out Theorem 6.11 therein and the discussion immediately before it.

> Georg Still (2018). Lectures on Parametric Optimization: An Introduction. Available Online at https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/6587.pdf